# Function in Swift will run, but will not execute "completion" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, function

I am trying to call a function in Swift. The first time I call it, it runs as intended, but the second time the completion handler if and else statements don't run. Despite this, I still know the function runs because I had it print "RAN" every time it ran. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help?

My Code:

```
[other code]

self.movieNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(50) + 1)

// Int movieNum is turned into String
let movieNumNSNumber = self.movieNum as NSNumber
let movieNumString: String = movieNumNSNumber.stringValue

self.checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown(movieID: movieNumString, completion: { seen in

     if seen {

          var i = 1
          var haveAllBeenSeen = 1
          while i <= 50 {
               let iNSNumber = i as NSNumber
               let iString: String = iNSNumber.stringValue

               self.checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown(movieID: movieNumString, completion: { seen in

                    if seen {
                         print("SEEN")
                    }
                    else {
                         print("NOT SEEN")
                         haveAllBeenSeen = 0
                    }
               })
               i += 1
          }
          if haveAllBeenSeen == 0 {
               self.swipingView()
          }
          else {

               [other code]         
          }      
     else {
          return
     }
})
```

Comment: *"but the second time the completion handler if and else statements don't run"* - sounds like the complication handler isn't been called - you should check and make sure `checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown` is actually calling it

Comment: Why did you make `haveAllBeenSeen` an integer with 1 & 0, instead of bool?

Comment: Go to `checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown` and make sure it is calling `completion` in all cases.

Comment: can you show the code for `checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I check if it is being called?

Comment: @BobSamuels As every one has suggested, you will need to look into `checkIfMovieHasAlreadyBeenShown` and see why it's not calling the complication handler